# How can i Test this API with Nodejs Lab module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, hapi.js

Can anyone help me with this test? How can I write a Unit Test for this API written by nodejs HAPI module. For testing I have to use Lab module.
This is the route.js file:

```
path: '/makes',
method: 'GET',
config: {
    handler: cars.getMakes
```

and this is the handler:

```
getMakes: function (request, reply) {

Make //this is a model of moongose in my DB
  .find()
  .sort('name')
  .exec( function(err, result) {

      if (err) {
         request.log(['server', 'database', 'error'], 'An error occurred during the execution of the query');
     }

     return reply(result)
        .code(200);
    });
 },
```

i have written it on my own but i have a error like this:

```
  getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND undefined
  at errnoException (dns.js:44:10)
  at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:94:26)
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: @GergoErdosi i don't need a writing service i have already written it but i have an error getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND undefined

      at errnoException (dns.js:44:10)
      at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:94:26)

Answer (score 0):

When I want to test an API, I usually write side code (using mocha and expect.js) that requests my API server (launched in test mode) and controls the answers for every possible case.

For your `/makes` rote, I'd just control what happens when there's no `Make`, and if they are correctly sorted as I want them to be.

Comment: thank you but if i have to control the return code 200 how can i do?

Comment: Depending on the HTTP request module you use, you just want to make sure that the return code is 200. I usually use `superagent`, and I have a `statusCode` variable in my response object.